# Doctor Dilemma: Michel won't join the Normandy as Ships Doctor

Tags: mass-effect-3

I told my old trusted doctor (Dr. Chakwas) to stay behind but didn't get prompted of gaining an asset. I then tried to recruit the younger one (Dr. Michel) and she keeps saying she has to think about it. Does she join later, or am I glitched?

Comment: DR? I'm not sure I understand...

Comment: @RavenDreamer I *think* he's talking about Dr. Chakwas and Dr. Michel.

Comment: I think so too.

Comment: yes I am :-) sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recruiting Doctor Michel to serve on the Normandy requires the use of a Charm or Intimidate dialog option (top left or bottom left of the wheel, respectively.) If you don't see either of these options in Blue (Charm/Paragon) or Red (Intimidate/Renegade), it means that Shepards reputation isn't strong enough to convince Dr. Michel to come aboard.

Go do some missions, improve your alignment, and then try again.

Comment: If this answers your question, you can **Accept** it by clicking on the checkmark to the right of it, and **Upvote** by clicking on the up arrow. That gives me credit for a good contribution to the site, and tells other users that you acknowledge good answers when you ask questions in the future!

Comment: I don't know if I'd like to recruit a Doctor by intimidating him...

Comment: How much does rep does this need?

Comment: @BenBrocka Not too much. I imported a Shepard with 100% Renegade and ~40% paragon from ME2 and had access to both dialogs when I first got to the Citadel.